# How to use Polygeist (cgeist) to translate C code into MLIR format?

Tags: c++, c, clang

I'm trying to use [Polygeist](https://github.com/llvm/Polygeist) to convert C code into MLIR format. I tried the following command line on windows 10 (with cgeist.exe already added to the path). And the output file only contains attributes.

> cgeist aes.c -S -o aes.scf.mlir

The output file:

```
module attributes {dlti.dl_spec = #dlti.dl_spec<#dlti.dl_entry<"dlti.endianness", "little">, #dlti.dl_entry<i64, dense<64> : vector<2xi32>>, #dlti.dl_entry<f80, dense<128> : vector<2xi32>>, #dlti.dl_entry<i1, dense<8> : vector<2xi32>>, #dlti.dl_entry<i8, dense<8> : vector<2xi32>>, #dlti.dl_entry<i16, dense<16> : vector<2xi32>>, #dlti.dl_entry<i32, dense<32> : vector<2xi32>>, #dlti.dl_entry<f16, dense<16> : vector<2xi32>>, #dlti.dl_entry<f64, dense<64> : vector<2xi32>>, #dlti.dl_entry<f128, dense<128> : vector<2xi32>>>, llvm.data_layout = "e-m:w-p270:32:32-p271:32:32-p272:64:64-i64:64-f80:128-n8:16:32:64-S128", llvm.target_triple = "x86_64-pc-windows-msvc19.34.31933", "polygeist.target-cpu" = "x86-64", "polygeist.target-features" = "+cx8,+fxsr,+mmx,+sse,+sse2,+x87", "polygeist.tune-cpu" = "generic"} {
}
```

Is there anything I should change to make it work? And maybe there's other C/C++ frontend support for MLIR that could be leveraged? Thanks a lot for any answer in advance :D

Comment: Please do not use screenshots,  share those information as text.

Answer (score 1):

Polygeist requires you to specify the C function to be lowered with `--function=<string>`. If not specified, the MLIR module is generated with an empty body.

To lower every function in the input code, use `--function=*`:

```
$ cgeist aes.c --function=* -S -o aes.scf.mlir
```

At this point, you have an MLIR code dumped using custom printers. You can obtain the generic MLIR format by passing the above output to `polygeist-opt`:

```
cgeist aes.c --function=* -S -o aes.scf.mlir | polygeist-opt --mlir-print-op-generic
```

### Example

Say we have the input file `sum.c`:

```c
int sum(int a, int b) {
    return a + b;
}
```

Running `cgeist sum.c --function=sum -S` we get:

```
module attributes {llvm.data_layout = "e-m:e-p270:32:32-p271:32:32-p272:64:64-i64:64-f80:128-n8:16:32:64-S128", llvm.target_triple = "x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu"}  {
  func @sum(%arg0: i32, %arg1: i32) -> i32 attributes {llvm.linkage = #llvm.linkage<external>} {
    %0 = arith.addi %arg0, %arg1 : i32
    return %0 : i32
  }
}
```

And running `cgeist sum.c --function=sum -S | polygeist-opt --mlir-print-op-generic` we get:

```
"builtin.module"() ( {
  "builtin.func"() ( {
  ^bb0(%arg0: i32, %arg1: i32):  // no predecessors
    %0 = "arith.addi"(%arg0, %arg1) : (i32, i32) -> i32
    "std.return"(%0) : (i32) -> ()
  }) {llvm.linkage = #llvm.linkage<external>, sym_name = "sum", type = (i32, i32) -> i32} : () -> ()
}) {llvm.data_layout = "e-m:e-p270:32:32-p271:32:32-p272:64:64-i64:64-f80:128-n8:16:32:64-S128", llvm.target_triple = "x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu"} : () -> ()
```